# Exception when creating new entity in RIA

Tags: silverlight, ria

I use **RIA + Silverlight** (probably last versions), Entity Framework. When **I insert a row** with code

```
 var context = new DataService();
 var script = new Script { Id = Guid.NewGuid(), User = User.Id };
 context.Scripts.Add(script);
 context.SubmitChanges((o) =>
     {         
      if (!o.HasError)
       {} // OK, but has never gone here yet
      else
       {
         o.MarkErrorAsHandled();
         Messaging.MessageBox("some error" + o.Error.Message);
        }
      }, null);
```

... it throws exception

---

**Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'Id', table Scripts, column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.**

---

When I try to debug, it goes well (to service), and that entity (Script) **HAS SET** 'Id' to some unique value. It looks like EntityFramework doesn't send that 'Id' to the database. It's possible ? :)

The 'Script' entity has only two columns:
- Id (Guid), User (int), and hasn't any foreign key yet.

Did I miss to set something ? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Did you originally create the table without an Identity Specification column and then make the PK an identity? If so you need to Refresh your model.

Also make sure the [Key] attribute is on your PK.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, thank you for you answer. It probably could work if I updated my model from database. But I did it otherwise - created database from model.

Now I know, I have to **set *StoredGeneratedPattern*** from **Identity** to ** None**